# Firebase: sendSignInLinkToEmail() throws: "The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project."

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';

firebase.initializeApp(...);

const auth = firebase.auth();

// I inspected `auth` here to verify that I'm authenticating 
// with the right project where the Email/Password sign-in provider
// is enabled.

auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => {
  // All fine until here, new user is created.
  auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, {
    url: window.location.href,
    handleCodeInApp: true,
  }).catch(error => {
    // Here, the error below is thrown.
  });
});
```

throws:

> [auth/operation-not-allowed] The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.

Interestingly, this works as expected:

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  // some logic here, and then:
  user
    .sendEmailVerification()
    .then(() => {
      // email is sent fine
    })
});
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/p29pjl556x) is a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the issue. Make sure to change the email address to one that hasn't been used before to see the error above.

What could be the reason for this error?

I'm using firebase@5.8.3

Comment: It is not enough to have the Email/Password Sign-In method activated.
You need to click on the Email/Password Sign-In method to open the pop-up window that will list the  Link Email authentication method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email verification is not a provider. That is why you can use it without seeing the `operation-not-allowed` error. It is only used to verify the email.

Email link sign-in is a method of sign-in and will allow the user to sign in with that email link. The former does not need to be enabled, whereas the latter does.
You can enable it following the instructions listed above by Doug.

Comment: Oh, I see now. For some reason, I thought that `sendSignInLinkToEmail` and `sendEmailVerification` are doing the same thing. But, apparently, it's two different things. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is and how to resolve it.  It sounds like you didn't enable the email/password authentication scheme in the Firebase console.  This is part of the [documented setup instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth):

> Before you begin
>
> 1. Add Firebase to your JavaScript project.
> 2. If you haven't yet connected your app to your Firebase project, do so from the Firebase console.
> 3. Enable Email/Password sign-in:
>
>    - In the Firebase console, open the Auth section.
>    - On the Sign in method tab, enable the Email/password sign-in method and click Save.

Comment: I explicitly mentioned in the question (see comment in code) that I checked that Email/Password is enabled.

Comment: I would double check that you actually committed this change in the console.  I can't imagine that the error message would lie.  If you feel that you've followed all the steps correctly, reach out to Firebase support to have them investigate, as I don't think there's much else to say. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: The change is committed for sure because I'm able to `signInWithEmailAndPassword`. I just updated the question with another observation that `user.sendEmailVerification()` works as expected.

Comment: I added a minimal repro to the question.